# CakePHP: Multiple validation rule - don't show mandatory hint in select options

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have created a form in CakePHP where the user can select languages for a project via checkboxes. For these checkboxes, I have implemented a validation rule (more than one checkbox has to be checked). Everything works fine, but ALL checkboxes show the "mandatory" star:

[image]

This is very ugly in my opinion because it seems to the user that every checkbox MUST be checked to complete the form. My validation rules look like the following:

```
    'Language' => array(
        'rule' => array(
            'multiple',
                array(
                    'min' => 1
            )
        ),
        'message' => 'Please select at least one language'
    )
```

'Language' is a seperate model and I use this for propagating my checkboxes. So, is there any trick to don't show this star near the checkboxes? The best would be to don't need to change anything on the Cake core...

**EDIT:**

The view code I am using for this is:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Project.Language', array('type' => 'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

Comment: Did you try `allowEmpty` true?

Comment: Try allowEmpty and require in the model

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies. Tried this, but neither allowEmpty, required nor a combination of both works for me. When I use them, ALL "mandatory" stars are gone. What I want achieve is something lik: Language*, Deutsch, French... So just the star on the Model name...

Comment: show the view code u are using

Comment: Yeah, just added it above

Comment: I have figured out now that I can suppress the highlighting of the checkbox labels via CSS. But this is in my opinion not very elegant. Or is there no other solution for this?